# Не работает  Request.QueryString в ASP 3.5 frm

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net

Здравствуйте!
Перехожу с одной страницы на другую:

```
 Response.Redirect("RegComplete.aspx?login=tb_Login.Text&pass=tb_Pass.Text&email=tb_Email.Text");
```

тут параметры login,pass, email.

**НО**

другая старница не получает значения((( поля пустые (значение **null**)

```
string username = Request.QueryString["login"];
string password = Request.QueryString["pass"];
string email = Request.QueryString["email"];
```

**Что я делаю не правильно?**

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
  Request["login"];
```

Comment: тот же самый результат :(

Comment: Тогда попробуйте посмотреть какое значение имеет само QueryString?

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("<a href='od.aspx?client={0}&data={1}> View Details</a>",
                  grouporder.Client, grouporder.Date)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, из-за перенаправления Request.QueryString не заполнен. 
Можно попробовать так:

```
NameValueCollection c = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
string username = с["login"];
string password = с["pass"];
string email = с["email"];
```